# switching between one activities using Touchscreens

Tags: android, hd44780

How can i switch between activities using Touch screen ( by drag of screen towards left using finger or mouse). I know it can be possible using gesture class, but the problem is i can't switch one activity from other.
Please suggest how it can be done. 
I'm new to Android. So please help and guide me.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

use [startActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29) to start a new activity.

Answer (score 1):

Just detect necessary gesture. When you get one, just start your second activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```